# F# Event is being triggered multiple times . . .?

Tags: wpf, events, f#, f#-3.0

I have this really simple program to get RSS-feeds from a website and populate a listbox with the items. Whenever the user selects an item and presses Enter, it should go to a web-page. this is the KeyUp event handler!

```
rssList.KeyUp
|> Event.filter (fun e -> rssList.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
|> Event.filter (fun (args:Input.KeyEventArgs) -> args.Key = Key.Enter)
|> Event.add  -> let feed = unbox<RSSFeed>  rssList.SelectItem)
                                            Process.Start(feed.Link) |> ignore)
```

What I'm getting is the following:

- the first time the event triggers, it works fine, the browser open and a page is loaded
- the second time it triggers TWO times, so now i get two browser windows opened and the page is loaded in both of them.
- the third time I get Three browser . . . You get the idea!

Anybody any idea why this is happening? My goal is (you guessed it) just to open 1 browser window and 1 page PER trigger

Comment: Looks like Event.add is missing some code (fun args ->). Could you please fix it?

Comment: the code above runs completely fine, i get no error about any 'missing' code. and It works just as expected. but there is multiple execution going on here and i have no idea why that happens

Comment: @ZaidAjaj For the sake of diagnosis, please try what Eugene suggested -- change your `Event.add -> ...` to `Event.add (fun args -> ...)` and try running the code again. It's always possible there's a bug in the compiler so you're not getting a parser or typing error when you should be.

Comment: @Jack I have already tried that, it was actually my first attemp! then I changed the event to a double-click handler and then made both events handled by different handlers . . . and i still got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

There are several compilation errors in your example including a malformed lambda expression, mismatched parentheses, incorrect identitfiers (`SelectItem` is not a property, I'm assuming you mean `SelectedItem` not `SelectedItems`), and incorrect indentation following the `let feed` binding.

Below is a simplified example that works as you intended. The selected item in the top ListBox is put into the bottom ListBox when the user hits Enter.

```
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open System.Windows.Input

[<EntryPoint>]
[<STAThread>]
let main argv = 
    let panel = new DockPanel()
    let listBox = new ListBox()
    for i in [| 1 .. 10 |] do
        listBox.Items.Add i |> ignore
    DockPanel.SetDock(listBox, Dock.Top)
    let listBox2 = new ListBox(Height = Double.NaN)
    panel.Children.Add listBox |> ignore
    panel.Children.Add listBox2 |> ignore
    listBox.KeyUp
        |> Event.filter (fun e -> listBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        |> Event.filter (fun e -> e.Key = Key.Enter)
        |> Event.add (fun e ->  let i = unbox<int> listBox.SelectedItem
                                listBox2.Items.Add(i) |> ignore)
    let win = new Window(Content = panel)
    let application = new Application()
    application.Run(win) |> ignore
    0
```

Comment: I copy-pasted that code and i played with it on the post page, however, the problem wasn't populating the listBox, i already managed that working good, but the problem was the events triggers it self again and again

Comment: I was trying a couple of things and I realised that i could implement the MouseButtonEventArgs.Handled property to prevent the event from re-triggering itself

Comment: @ZaidAjaj It sounds like what's happening is that you are getting multiple handlers attached to the `KeyUp` event. (Perhaps you are adding the handler inside another event handler that is firing often?) Sign up for the `KeyUp` event once.

Comment: I actually did that, and looking at run-time, it triggers itself 1 more time every trigger, so the forth time someone opens a page, he gets 4 pages, I even made a seperate handler for it but didn't work either! then at last, i implemented the Handled property of the event arguments and it worked! (see below) :)

Answer (score -1):

I got it working properly by implementing the Handled property of the event args with the following:

```
let doubleClick = new MouseButtonEventHandler(fun sender (args:MouseButtonEventArgs) ->
    let listBox = unbox<ListBox> sender
    match listBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0 with
    | true -> 
        let listBox = unbox<ListBox> sender
        let feed = unbox<RSSFeed> listBox.SelectedItem
        Process.Start(feed.Link) |> ignore
        args.Handled <- true; ()
    | false -> 
        args.Handled <- true; ())
```

thanks to everyone who helped me here!